# Call stored procedure airflow using Oracleoperator

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures, airflow, cx-oracle

I'm new to Python. I am using apache airflow and a task I am calling a stored procedure oracle. I see error illegal variable name / number

```
t1 = OracleOperator(
    task_id='Exe_PA',
    oracle_conn_id='DEV_SR',
    parameters=('1', 'TC', 'ESPA', '99', '2', '100', '28-08-2019', '0'),
    sql= 'Begin pno_validacion_inicial(); end;',
    dag=dag)
```

> [2019-08-29 18:09:21,089] {dbapi_hook.py:168} INFO - Begin pno_validacion_inicial(); end; with parameters ('1', 'TC', 'ESPA', '99', '2', '100', '28-08-2019', '0')
>   [2019-08-29 18:09:21,091] {**init**.py:1580} ERROR - ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models/**init**.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
>       result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/operators/oracle_operator.py", line 63, in execute
>       parameters=self.parameters)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 169, in run
>       cur.execute(s, parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Since release 2.1.0, the [apache-airflow-providers-oracle](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-oracle/) provider now has a [OracleStoredProcedureOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-oracle/stable/_api/airflow/providers/oracle/operators/oracle/index.html#airflow.providers.oracle.operators.oracle.OracleStoredProcedureOperator) which allows the calling of stored procedures.

(This was also possible before, but this operator makes it easier and also supports [out parameters](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html#pl-sql-stored-procedures).)

To pass an *out parameter*, simply provide the type constructor as the value for the out parameter, e.g. `int` for a number, `str` for a text field etc. Of course, in parameters are just normal values.

The result of the operator (which is pushed via [XComs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html) by default) is the parameter list or dict (depending on the type provided) where the *out parameters* have been replaced with their returned values.

The hook class used by the operator provides a `callproc` method which works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `pno_validacion_inicial()` contains no parameters but you are passing 8 parameters. Your SQL should look like this instead:

`begin pno_validacion_inicial(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8); end;`

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the [documentation](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/operators/oracle_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.oracle_operator.OracleOperator) you can see that parameters need to be a mapping or iterable. Your code should like like:

```
t1 = OracleOperator(
     task_id='Exe_PA',
     oracle_conn_id='DEV_SR',
     parameters=({'param1':'1', 'param2':'TC', 'param3':'ESPA', 'param4':'99', 'param5':'2', 'param6':'100', 'param7':'28-08-2019', 'param8':'0'}),
     sql= 'Begin pno_validacion_inicial(:param1, :param2, :param2, :param3, :param4, :param5, :param6, :param7, :param8 ); end;',
     dag=dag)
```